# Rails : Sass can't find node_modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, sass

I'm currently making a rails app with react and webpack.
I want to import a css file in my node_module with sass:

`@import '~@coreui/icons/css/coreui-icons.css';`

In my js i CAN import this file using `import '@coreui/icons/css/coreui-icons.css';`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my issue.
I use Webpack so I moved my scss files in the assets/styles folder, and its worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command

```
sudo npm install --save-dev  --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

If this doesn't work try to install from a mirror 
npm install -g mirror-config-china --registry=http://registry.npm.taobao.org npm install node-sass